# How do I create shortcodes for displaying nodes according to tags?

Tags: hooks

I want to create a shortcode, which is a specific code that lets you do nifty things with very little effort. Shortcodes can embed files or create objects that would normally require lots of complicated, ugly code in just one line.

I would create it for displaying the nodes on the basis of tag. The final shortcode will look like `[article tag=sports]`. WordPress provides the shortcode API but there is not any option for Drupal 7.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with **tokens**? Any relationship or similarity with shortcodes?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So far, you just stated facts, and those are quite clear. You didn't ask any explicit question (the title doesn't count as explicit question). What exactly don't you understand about creating shortcodes? Are you looking for a module (which is an off-topic request for us)? Are you trying to understand if in Drupal we call the shortcodes differently?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to create shortcode in drupal 7.Is there any function,hook or anything?

Comment: Google told that there is a shortcode for Drupal 7. See https://www.drupal.org/project/shortcode

Comment: Aww please I already know about it.  Please check again my question.And  don't believe in google every time @Gulok

Comment: @John, then you must ask explicit question. With that kind of question we can only give suggestion/opinion. If I understand your question what you want is a plugin ffor WYSIWYG to handle the shortcode. And if that is create you have to create a plugin for example in Ckeditor.